# Will the 'Google Contacts CardDAV API' be switched off together with the 'Contacts API' in summer 2021?

Tags: google-api

**Background:**

I noticed that the Google Contacts API (https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3) will be switched off in summer 2021.

I'm currently using the "Google *Contacts* CardDAV API" (https://developers.google.com/contacts/carddav) to synchronize contact information with Google.

**Question:**

Is the CardDAV API a subset of the Contacts API and therefore switched off in summer 2021, as well?

Three points make me believe this:

- The API-name starts with "Google Contacts ..."
- The URL to the API Documentation starts with: "https://developers.google.com/**contacts**/..."
- Navigate to: Google API-Console, open "Google Contacts CardDAV API", click on "Learn more"
  --> you will be redirected to the expiring Contacts API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No answer here from google over months :-(

but a new specification document clarifies this now:

https://developers.google.com/people/carddav